# Offset Loop by 1 , Limit next loop to 1 (Most Recent) Post

Tags: loop, recent-posts, offsets

I have a loop that I would like to Offset by 1 so the most recent post is not displayed, and another loop where I only want 1 item which would be the most recent post.

These are the loops I tried: for both:

Offset Loop: 
`<?php query_posts('offset=1');
if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>`

and Most Recent Post Loop:
`<?php query_posts('posts_per_page=1');
if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>`

The page doesnt load for me when I tried this, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither of those are complete loops. That is, in both you have the start of an `if` but not the end of it, and the start of a `while` loop, but no the end of it. Also, you shouldn't be using [`query_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts) either, as it over writes the main query and is rarely the right function for pulling posts. [`get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) would be better.

I would do this, using one as an example:

```
<?php $r = get_posts('offset=1'); 
    if ( !empty($r) ) : 
        foreach  ( $r as $post ) : 
            setup_postdata($post);
            // stuff
        endforeach;
    endif; ?>
```

That should solve your problem with the page not loading.

What you are doing can be done with a single loop though, since get_posts without the offset will pull everything. You just need to take the first element as the recent post and loop through the rest.